# Python SSL/TLS Server: TCP to SSL/TLS after plaintext handshake

Tags: python, ssl, openssl

I have python client server which is functioning as expected.

```
ssl_sock = ssl.wrap_socket(s,ssl_version=ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1_1, cert_reqs=ssl.CERT_NONE,server_side=True,certfile="cert.pem",keyfile="key.pem")
```

I have specific requirement wherein client and server perform handshake by sending plain text message over TCP. When the client receives a specific string from the server, client should initiate SSL handshake by sending clientHello() and socket should be changed to SSL.

```
Client                        Server

 +                            +
 |                            |
 |           Hello            |
 +---------------------------->
 |                            |
 |                            |
 |            2001 OK         |
 <----------------------------+
 |                            |
 |            ClienHello      |
 +---------------------------->
 |                            |
 |            ServerHello     |
 <----------------------------+
 |                            |
 |                            |
 |                            |
 +                            +
```

I would like to know is there any function to detect an incoming ClientHello() from the client. Below is the list of SSL header values I got from Wireshark for different SSL/TLS versions.

```
 SSL 3.0 0x0300 
 TLS 1.0 0x0301 
 TLS 1.1 0x0302 
 TLS 1.2 0x0303
```

I am looking for a sample server code written using any python ssl/tls package.

Any help is greatly appreciated.